# Third party applet not working in browser

Tags: java, applet

In my JSP we were using the third party applet like this:

```html
<applet code="com.radio.applet.ModelApplet" archive="include/applet/wpApplet.jar>
    <param name="resourceID" value="admin" />
</applet>
```

Since the browsers are no longer supporting the applet, how can I make it work?

Comment: It is possible to write a local swing application that wraps the applet, like the appletviewer java tool. However I am not sure whether that covers all. Try it.

Comment: *"how can I make it work?"* Do you possess the technology to move through time (backwards)? If not, I'd suggest recoding the applet in Javascript.